# Finale software playing quieter than any other software or application

Tags: windows-7, audio

I just downloaded Finale and it is working great except for the audio.  Even on my highest volume it is much quieter than any other application.  I ran an audio test and was successful, but I cannot find any other way I can change the volume.

I have Windows 7 and a Dell Latitude D531 Laptop. What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Each application can have its own volume slider in the windows audio mixer.  if you right click the speaker icon on the task bar, and choose "Open Volume Mixer" you should see an option for each of the opened apps on your machine.  You'll need to have Finale running for it to appear in the mixer.  Keep in mind, if it is not set to max, the volume is controlled proportionally to the Device volume (speakers).